# Unable to the Linux Script for executing a Java Program

Tags: java, linux, bash, noclassdeffounderror

I am unable to resolve this issue in which i was trying to executing a java program through bash script .

Why i am getting this error ??

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/QuoteTester
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.QuoteTester
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: com.QuoteTester.  Program will exit.
```

This is my script content  `quotetest.sh`

```
java -cp ./com/ug_ugbapi-all.jar com.QuoteTester $1
```

I am executing the script ,  this way

```
./quotetest.sh GOOG
```

From the  directory from where i am executing this script quotetest.sh , in that i got a directory by name **com**  under which i got `ug_ugbapi-all.jar and QuoteTester.class classes` .

Tried every option (placing all the files in same folder com , but nothing worked )

Could anybody please tell me how to resolve it ??

Comment: before closing this thread , can i know the answer pleaseeee ?

Comment: two questions: 1) if you run java from the shell does it work? 2) what's the first line of you script? #!/bin/sh ? Are you sure you're not spawning a shell that is missing some fundamental environment variables?

Comment: is this needed #!/bin/sh ??

Comment: try to change it to #!/bin/bash , because I think you're missing some environment variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your given classpath, Java is *only* going to look in the jar file.  For it to find the class file outside of the jar, you have to modify your `-cp` argument:

```
java -cp ./com/ug_ugbapi-all.jar:. com.QuoteTester $1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because the `com/QuoteTester` class cannot be found, which means that the `com/QuoteTester` class is not on the classpath.